# How to enable/disable button with validation in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Expected: After Entering Valid Email ID pattern button should be enabled.
Happened: After Entering Valid Email ID button goes disabled.
This is my Input textfield in HTML:

```
 <form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="emailID">Enter Email ID</label>
<input type="email"  class="form-control" id="emailID" ng-model="c.emailID" placeholder="Enter EmailID">    
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Password">Enter Password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" ng-model="c.password" placeholder="Enter Password">
</div>
    <button type="submit" ng-model="button" ng-click ="submit(c)" ng-disabled="c.emailID" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

This is my AngularjS Script :`

```
var myApp1=angular.module('myApp',[]);
  myApp1.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope)
{   
   $scope.submit=function(c)
   {   
   }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First add a name to your form and to your input:

```
<form name="myForm" class="form-inline">
<input type="email" name="emailID"  class="form-control" id="emailID" ng-model="c.emailID" placeholder="Enter EmailID">
```

Then change your ng-disabled:

```
<button type="submit" ng-model="button" ng-click ="submit(c)" ng-disabled="!(myForm.emailID.$valid && myForm.emailID.$dirty)" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

$dirty is added because we want the user to actually enter an value before we enable. Or you can add required on your input if its a compulsory input field.

Also refer: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

Comment: yes this answer will work .name a form and check for field validity.